# Trigger handler on a specific condition

Tags: ansible

How can I notify an ansible handler on a specific condition?

My scenario is as such;

```
  - name: git clone repo
    notify: build
    git:
      repo=git://example.com/repo.git
      dest=~/repo
```

This will notify the `build` handler, which basically does a `make;make install` from the repo directory, and creates a file called: `/usr/local/include/something.h`. All fine so far.

In the event that the git repo is already in place, and no updates are present, then build handler won't fire, and the `make;make install` won't run.

How can I cause the `build` handler to fire if the file `/usr/local/include/something.h` does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found to do this works, but feels a bit circuitous.

Posting this as an answer for others, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way to achieve my goal;

```
- name: install repo
  command: /bin/true
  args:
    creates: /usr/local/include/something.h
  notify: build2
```

The `creates` clause acts as a guard for this task. If the `something.h` is already in place, it will be skipped. If it is not there, then the task always evaluates to changed, thus notifying my `build` handler.